# Routing not working in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I'm new to Angularjs and have been learning about routing.

I created a test application for routing but somehow it doesn't works!

I have thoroughly checked all the official documentation and tried different combinations but not been able to make it work yet

Here is the code: http://plnkr.co/edit/msjFJfKPq5xm588RJjNP

someone please help!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'] );
```

to

```
var app = angular.module('app');
```

in your controllers and everything will be fine

By adding second argument to the module function you [register new module](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/docs/api/ng/function/angular.module).

Updated your [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/l90HD9?p=preview)

**Update**

About contact view. There is another typo:

```
templateURL: 'contact.html'
```

and should be:

```
templateUrl: 'contact.html'
```

Plunk updated.

Comment: Thanks so much Andrey, it totally works!

but somehow the **contact** view still doesn't works. Any idea why?

cheers once again

Comment: I knew that would be some silly mistake and I was right! Thanks one again for pointing that out. You have been a life saver :)